# Using PHP to separate read / writes

Tags: php, mysql

We have decided that we are going to move from a single database to a replicated database in a master-slave architecture and are going to get all of our reads to go to the slave and writes to the master.

The reason we are going down this route is an addition to our product means that we are getting a large increase in database connections which leads to performance problems with our reporting suite.

We are using MySQL(5.1.55) and the application is developed in PHP.

A couple of general queries on this:

- How would you tell the application which db to read from?  Would you do it within the PHP? Or just something like mysqldnd_ms or mysql proxy?
- Where would ajax requests read from? We have a page which allows users to flag a record.  This is then saved in the database and users can see which records have been flagged.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: All you need to have is two connections strings. One for read and one for write. No special software required.

Comment: If that is the case - how does it work for reading data that was written from by ajax and needs to be read immediately? Can that be read from the slave?

Comment: You can't rely on replication to be instantaneous.

Comment: You would need a full on database cluster. Master-Slave won't work for that.

Comment: You might want to switch to a different database.  PostgreSQL supports [synchronous replication](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Synchronous_replication), which corrects a severe flaw that @ethrbunny points out.  There *is* a delay in MySQL replication.  While it's not much, usually only a second or two, it can make for a very jarring experience if you're doing split reads and writes.

Comment: Under heavy load I've seen it stretch to several hours. Replication is single threaded whereas the Master may be working on multiple threads simultaneously.